# How can I implement a string stack with a switch statement?

Tags: java

I would like to implement my StringStack in a switch statement how can i make this work in java. it sais i cant push() and argument with a char value. What is the best way around this for my validation method?

```
package xmlvalidator;

public class BasicXmlValidator implements XmlValidator {


    @Override
    public String[] validate(String xmlDocument) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int charIndex = 0;
        char currentCharacter;
        String characterString;


        while (charIndex < xmlDocument.length()) {
            currentCharacter = xmlDocument.charAt(charIndex);
            characterString = Character.toString(currentCharacter);

            switch (currentCharacter) {
            case '(': StringStack.push(currentCharacter);
                break;
            case '[': StringStack.push(currentCharacter);
            break;
            case '{': StringStack.push(currentCharacter);
            break;
            case ')': StringStack.push(currentCharacter);
            break;
            case ']': StringStack.push(currentCharacter);
            break;
            case '}': StringStack.push(currentCharacter);
            break;

            }
        }


        return null;
    }

}




package xmlvalidator;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class BasicStringStack implements StringStack {

    public int count; // Number of Items in the array

    public String[] stackItems; // The array that holds the stack items


    public BasicStringStack(int initialSize) {
        count = 0;
        stackItems = new String[initialSize];
    }


    @Override
    public void push(String item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (count == stackItems.length) {
            int newLength = (stackItems.length + 1);
            String[] tempArray = new String[newLength];
            arraycopy(stackItems, 0, tempArray, 0, stackItems.length);
            stackItems = tempArray;
        }

        stackItems[count++] = item;


    }


    @Override
    public String pop() {

        if (count == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return stackItems[--count];
        }


    }


    @Override
    public String peek(int position) {

        if ((position > count - 1) || (position < 0)) {
            return null; // outside Bounds
        } else {
            return stackItems[count - position - 1];
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: your function `public String[] validate(String xmlDocument);` returns null but it supposed to return string array , and your `int charIndex = 0;` is not incremented and you have a string array and your pushing character in it

Comment: I havnt finished the code yet. I just want to know how to push my character value.

Comment: are you using StringStack of apache: [link]https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/StringStack.html[link]

Comment: @AdaLovelace if either of the answers below have helped you, consider up-voting them. If one has answered your question, you can mark it as the answer with the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You have the current char stored in a string using             `characterString = Character.toString(currentCharacter);`  just use it to push into stack.

```
StringStack.push(currentCharacter);

change to

StringStack.push(currentString);
```

Comment: that was my logic thats why i made the characterString but i get a compile error when i do that because it wants me to change my push() method to a static method which i cannot do because i have a j unit tester that i have to pass. is there any other option

Comment: Try changing your push method to get argument as character .

Comment: I cant because it has to be a StringStack

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is exactly as Java describes it to you. You pass a `char` to a method that expects `String`. The best fix would be

```
Stringstack.push(characterString);
```

---

Aside: because switch lets you fall through, you can rewrite it as

```
switch (currentCharacter) {
   case '(':
   case '[': 
   case '{': 
   case ')':
   case ']': 
   case '}':
    StringStack.push(characterString);
    break;
}
```

---

Further aside: I did **not** address other potential problems in the code, but sought only to address the question asked.

Comment: Stringstack.push(new String(currentCharacter));

Comment: Im not understanding that code and where it goes it doesnt fix it

Comment: The code already has `characterString = Character.toString(currentCharacter);` - just push that

Comment: StringStack.push(characterString);

Comment: i cant do that because it wants me to change my push to static which will mess up my hole program because I have to use a j unit tester which will not allow